# VS2008 Intellisense screwing up when I add an XMLNS: namespace declaration to my stylesheet

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, xslt, intellisense

When I have the following (default) declaration in my XSL file, everything works fine.  when I type a "<" character, intellisense window pops up with all the xsl: namespace choices as expected.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
```

However, when I add this simple xmlns: reference, intellisense somehow loses it's little electronic mind, and forgets all about the xsl: namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
            xmlns:ftid="http://www.boeing.com/FTID-ML"
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
```

The only options intellisense shows with the ftid namespace included are

```
<!--
<![CDATA[
<?
```

If I remove the reference, intellisense wakes up and works normally.  I've tried re-starting VS08, and I'm at a loss.

**EDIT:**  To be clear, I am NOT trying to get intellisense for the ftid: namespace; rather, the intellisense for the xsl: namespace STOPS working when I add the xmlns:ftid reference, then starts working again when I remove it.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: voted to close - nothing helpful in the solution "reinstall VS2008".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I reinstalled VS2008 (for other reasons) and the intellisense works fine now.  I hate it when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Does it reference a schema?  If so, you can put the schema it references into a directory named something like:

```
{Visual Studio install drive}:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas
```

and then it *should* work (can't test it locally right now, sorry).

See [this article on doing something similar for XInclude](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000744.html).

Comment: I'm not trying to get intellisense to work for my ftid: namespace; rather the intellisense for the xsl: namespace STOPS working when I add the xmlns:ftid reference, and starts working again when I remove it.

Comment: I was wondering if adding in the other XSD as a 'known' namespace via this mechanism might make things start working again. Perhaps even a dummy XSD with just the namespace would free things up.

I know, it's stupid that it doesn't just work. It must be a bug.